# Is there a way to remove css :target selection?

Tags: html, css

```css
p:target {
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: aqua;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#first">Click here for first-block</a>
<a href="#second">Click here for second-block</a>
<a href="#third">Click here for third-block</a>
<a href="#fourth">Click here for fourth-block</a>
<a href="#fifth">Click here for fifth-block</a>
<a href="#sixth">Click here for sixth-block</a>

<hr>

<b>Result-</b>
<p id="first">1st block</p>
<p id="second">2nd block</p>
<p id="third">3rd block</p>
<p id="fourth">4th block</p>
<p id="fifth">5th block</p>
<p id="sixth">6th block</p>
```

[:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

step 1. click on the `click here for fourth block`, observe the 4th block is selected
step2:  click `reload this page` in chrome v114 browser , observe the selection of the fourth block persists always unless something else is selected.

How do I make this persistence of the selection go away after reloading page?

I cleaned cookies, closed/reopened browser but still the selection persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The persistence of the selection after reloading the page is a default behavior of browsers. The ":target" pseudo-class in CSS is used to select an element that is the target of the current URL fragment identifier. When you click on a link with an anchor tag pointing to a specific ID, the browser scrolls to that element and applies the ":target" styles to it.

To make the selection go away after reloading the page, you can use JavaScript to remove the ":target" state from the element. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var currentHash = window.location.hash;
  if (currentHash) {
    // Remove the hash from the URL without scrolling
    history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);

    // Remove the :target styles from the element
    var targetElement = document.querySelector(currentHash);
    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.classList.remove('target');
    }
  }
});
```

In this example, we listen for the "DOMContentLoaded" event, which fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed. We check if there is a hash in the URL (indicating that an element has been targeted). If a hash exists, we use the history.replaceState() method to remove the hash from the URL without causing the page to scroll. Then, we find the targeted element using document.querySelector() and remove the "target" class (or any other class you have used for the ":target" styles) from it.

Make sure to add the "target" class to the targeted elements in your HTML:

```
<p id="first" class="target">1st block</p>
<p id="second" class="target">2nd block</p>
<p id="third" class="target">3rd block</p>
<p id="fourth" class="target">4th block</p>
<p id="fifth" class="target">5th block</p>
<p id="sixth" class="target">6th block</p>
```

By adding the "target" class to the elements, you can remove it using JavaScript when the page loads, effectively removing the ":target" styles from the element.

Comment: Did you generate this with ChatGPT?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong ... Point 1 and 2 also not required I suppose ....(Point 1) `<p id="first" class="target">1st block</p>
<p id="second" class="target">2nd block</p>
<p id="third" class="target">3rd block</p>
<p id="fourth" class="target">4th block</p>
<p id="fifth" class="target">5th block</p>
<p id="sixth" class="target">6th block</p>`

and 
(Point2) ` var targetElement = document.querySelector(currentHash); if (targetElement) { targetElement.classList.remove('target'); }`

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.